# coding raw_input prompt into multiple lines...?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, indentation, raw-input

newbie here. I got this raw_input prompt inside a loop so it is indented;

```
userInput = raw_input('Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last\
hand, or e to end game: ')
```

when I run this I get 2 tabs of space (indentation) between "last" and "hand". Is there a way to get rid of this gap?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Doesn't reproduce for me :)

Comment: @Berkhan Probably there is an extra tab after `last\` or before `hand` in your script.

Comment: there is a tab, no doubt about that, but @falsetru 's answer solves the problem, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [string literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation):

```
userInput = raw_input(
    'Enter n to deal a new hand, r to replay the last '
    'hand, or e to end game: ')
```

> Multiple adjacent string literals (delimited by whitespace), possibly
>   using different quoting conventions, are allowed, and their meaning is
>   the same as their concatenation. Thus, "hello" 'world' is equivalent
>   to "helloworld". This feature can be used to reduce the number of
>   backslashes needed, to split long strings conveniently across long
>   lines, or even to add comments to parts of strings